Prompting/Requiring ERC-20 Approval Before Before Function Call
I'm working on integrating some smart contracts which transfer users' ERC20 tokens into a frontend. I know I must have the user approve the smart contract's address to use the X amount of tokens, but what I am wondering is how people normally prompt the token approval and require the approval before the smart contract function call?
Or do people just prompt a token approval, then prompt the smart contract transaction & allow the transaction to fail if the approval was not granted?
Is there some standard or code examples that do this? I can't find anything about it online. I'm specifically using wagmi's contractWrite and vercel.

Yes, it's two separate transactions. So, the first is asking for an approval and the second transfers the tokens and possibly does some internal computing.
However, many DeFi sites ask for an infinite approval, regardless of how much is actually needed for that interaction. This way they don't need to ask for an approval after that anymore, and users can interact with the protocol with just one transaction.
But asking for an infinite approval is a security risk. If there is a security issue in the smart contract, it may be able to drain all of your tokens, since you have given it allowance to withdraw an infinite amount.
To reduce the possibility of errors, you can check that the approval has been set before trying to move the tokens.
